How do I format pseudo-bibliographic paragraphs (not real biblatex citations) in Pandoc markdown for PDF & EPUB outputs?
Say in the middle of the text I want to create pseudo-bibliographic entries that are just normal paragraphs but formatted like a bibliography. In LibreOffice, this is trivial: I just change the indentation of the paragraph.
I tried to create a mock-up in LibreOffice, but the site tells me I can't post images if my reputation is below 10. But to describe it, it's a hanging indentation like a bibliography, but it is a pseudo bibliography because it's just a paragraph meant to look like a bibliographic item.
Instead, I'll make the following mock-up using a code block:
Oblique delenit salutatus eos id, an legimus maiorum sed, sea omittantur necessitatibus et. See the following: 

Auditore, Ezio. (1635). Mediocrem rationibus neglegentur no sed. Florence,
          Italy: Sea erant ceteros imperdiet ex.

Mea cu habeo mentitum oporteat, pro ut commodo eloquentiam instructior.


So far this is a technique in Pandoc I haven't learned yet. I'll be using this to export to PDF and EPUB, if that helps.
I've searched online and checked the manual but haven't found what I want. HTML tags in markdown seems to work for formatting on EPUB, but it didn't work for PDFs. I need a solution that exports to both.

You could either 1) export to PDF via HTML, 2) export to PDF via LaTeX and repeat the section once in raw HTML and once in raw TeX, or 3) write a custom https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html

I'll look into that thanks.

One possible approach would be to turn the pseudo-reference into a real reference entry, store it to a separate file, and then use a filter like multibib to create a second bibliography.
A specialized filter for your specific use-case, that uses a similar approach as multibib, should be a bit more work, but might end up being simpler to use and could give better results.

Hmm, what if I just want French indentation like for a play with hanging indentation perhaps instead of a pseudo bibliography? I don't think this would work for what I'm thinking of.
